# Redirect to www web config rule with subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

how to implement redirect rule in webconfig according this

1. http://quietincomes.com/ (if www is not in url) redirect to http://www.quietincomes.com/
2. http://www.shayam.quietincomes.com/ redirect to http://www.quietincomes.com/shayam
3. http://shayam.quietincomes.com/ (if www is not in url) redirect to http://www.quietincomes.com/shayam

In http://www.shyam.quietincomes.com..... This shyam is dynamically created..
It can be www.harshit.quietincomes.com, www.ankush.quietincomes.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<rule name="Primary hostname redirect" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^quietincomes.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.quietincomes.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="www.shayam redirect" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.shayam.quietincomes.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.quietincomes.com/shayam/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="shayam redirect" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^shayam.quietincomes.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.quietincomes.com/shayam/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

If you want the subdomain part to be dynamic, something like this (haven't tested it!):

```
<rule name="Dynamic redirect" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^(.*)\.quietincomes\.com$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.quietincomes\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.quietincomes.com/{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The match rule specifies a back-reference (.*) which is used in the redirect url ({C:1})

Comment: I think the {HTTP_HOST} pattern in the first example requires the dot to be escaped:

`^quietincomes\.com$` instead of `^quietincomes.com$`